# Error in joining data from two tables in Big Query

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I'm a beginner in SQL and currently taking the Google Data Analytics Professional Certificate course on Coursera. Long story short, the instructor gave us code to join data in Big Query and even while using their code line for line, I'm getting an error. I have a dataset named employee_data containing two tables titled 'employees' and 'departments'. We are tasked with just getting a list of employees with their department names and roles. The error reads "Unrecognized name: employees at [9:3]"

```
SELECT
  employees.name AS employee_name,
  employees.role AS employee_role,
  departments.name AS department_name
FROM
  `my-project-050923-386223.employee_data.employees`
INNER JOIN
  `my-project-050923-386223.employee_data.departments` ON 
  employees.department_id = departments.department_id;
```

I double checked all of the table and column names to make sure they were correct and corresponded to my query. I removed the "my-project-050923-386223" before the database and table name and I tried with and without the quotes. I just kept getting the same error. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I'd try table aliases.

Comment: `my-project-050923-386223.employee_data.employees` exists `employees` alone without the rest not